# Aggregate rows between two rows with certain value

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, case, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to formulate a query to aggregate rows that are between rows with a specific value: in this example I want to collapse and sum time of all rows that have an ID other than 1, but still show rows with ID 1.

This is my table:

```
  ID | Time 
 ----+-----------
   1 |        60
   2 |        10
   3 |        15
   1 |        30
   4 |       100
   1 |        20
```

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
  ID     |      Time 
 --------+-----------
   1     |        60
   Other |        25
   1     |        30
   Other |       100
   1     |        20
```

I have attempted to SUM and add a condition with CASE, or but so far my solutions only get me to sum ALL rows and I lose the intervals, so I get this:

```
  ID         |      Time 
 ------------+-----------
   Other     |        125
   1         |        110
```

Any help or suggestions in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you would need to also have a column which provides the order you assume exists in the table.  I.e. we need a column which says that `1 60` is the first record, `2 10` the second record, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the groupings.  SQLite is not great for this sort of manipulation, but you can do it by summing the "1" values up to each value.

In SQLite, we can use the `rowid` column for the ordering:

```
select (case when id = 1 then '1' else 'other' end) as which,
       sum(time)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.rowid <= t.rowid and t2.id = 1) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by (case when id = 1 then '1' else 'other' end), grp
order by grp, which;
```